# MAMP 2.0.3 - Apache not restarting at all

Tags: apache, mamp

I have been trying to install IonCube for the past 2 days on my localhost, and it just won't show up. Today I tried changing the PHP versions to force some sort of hard refresh, and MAMP is not changing versions.

By the looks of this, in my opinion, Apache is not restarting at all, how can I force it to stop with a Terminal command or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and sweet is to restart your machine entirely, fine for if you're just a local developer.